# bundle install includes all dependencies, even with --without

Tags: dependencies, installation, bundle, bundler

I am trying to install [Redmine 2.1.2](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall) on an Ubuntu 12.04, but I have a problem of dependencies. In short, I am running the following command:

```bsh
bundle install --without development test mysql sqlite
```

And bundle tries to install all the dependencies, even the one for the groups listed above and the ones not corresponding to my platform (which is `ruby` and not `jruby`).

Here is a link to the Gemfile I am using : http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/entry/tags/2.1.2/Gemfile

The generated `Gemfile.lock` is the following :

```rb
GEM
  remote: http://localhost:6789/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.8)
      actionpack (= 3.2.8)
      mail (~> 2.4.4)
    actionpack (3.2.8)
      activemodel (= 3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.0)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.1.3)
    activemodel (3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.8)
      activemodel (= 3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.8)
      activemodel (= 3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
    activesupport (3.2.8)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    builder (3.0.0)
    coderay (1.0.8)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    fastercsv (1.5.5)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.1)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.2.0, < 5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.7.5)
    mail (2.4.4)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    metaclass (0.0.1)
    mime-types (1.19)
    mocha (0.12.3)
      metaclass (~> 0.0.1)
    multi_json (1.3.6)
    mysql (2.8.1)
    mysql2 (0.3.11)
    net-ldap (0.3.1)
    pg (0.14.1)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.4.1)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-openid (1.3.1)
      rack (>= 1.1.0)
      ruby-openid (>= 2.1.8)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.8)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.8)
      actionpack (= 3.2.8)
      activerecord (= 3.2.8)
      activeresource (= 3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.8)
    railties (3.2.8)
      actionpack (= 3.2.8)
      activesupport (= 3.2.8)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rmagick (2.13.1)
    ruby-openid (2.1.8)
    shoulda (2.11.0)
    sprockets (2.1.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.6)
    test-unit (2.5.2)
    thor (0.16.0)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.33)
    yard (0.8.2.1)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter
  activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter
  activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter
  builder (= 3.0.0)
  coderay (~> 1.0.6)
  fastercsv (~> 1.5.0)
  i18n (~> 0.6.0)
  jquery-rails (~> 2.0.2)
  jruby-openssl
  mocha (= 0.12.3)
  mysql
  mysql2 (~> 0.3.11)
  net-ldap (~> 0.3.1)
  pg (>= 0.11.0)
  rack-openid
  rails (= 3.2.8)
  rdoc (>= 2.4.2)
  rmagick (>= 2.0.0)
  ruby-openid (~> 2.1.4)
  shoulda (~> 2.11)
  sqlite3
  test-unit
  yard
```

In the `.bundle/config` file, there is a ligne `BUNDLE_WITHOUT: development:test:mysql:sqlite`.

I tried to remove the `.bundle`, the `Gemfile.lock`, the `~/.bundler` and the `~/.gems` as indicated on the troubleshooting page of bundler on github (which I can't post since I don't have 10 reputations) but it did not change anything.

I am getting the gems from a local repository in which I have only the gems I needed. So I modified the `source` in the `Gemfile` (that's why you have a `remote: http://localhost:6789` in the `Gemfile.lock`). Because of this, the install fails since bundler is looking for gems that does not exists on my server and that are, theoratically, not needed.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Maybe bundle install --without development --without test --without mysql  --without sqlite ? (please notify @ me, I don't check for answers)

Answer (score 4):

You may need to add a `:require => false` to some of the gems in those groups.